# How to add transition for conditionally rendered view in SwiftUI?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

How to add a transition for a conditionally rendered view inside a `GroupedListStyle` list? to achieve something like the conditional `DatePicker` from the "Do Not Disturb" section in Settings (see GIF below).

Adding `transition` and `animation` for the conditionally rendered view does not seem to work.

```
if condition {
    Toggle(isOn: $foo) {
        HStack {
            Text("Foo")
        }
    }
    .transition(.opacity)
    .animation(.easeInOut)
    .toggleStyle(SwitchToggleStyle(tint: Color.red)
}
```

[image]

**Implementation based on pawello2222**

The animation is that smooth especially when the view about to disappear. The transition position was animated from frame 1 to 11 but suddenly disappeared from frame 12 onwards.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It might be better to keep the *animation-related* logic (like `withAnimation`) *inside* the view.

A possible solution is to create a custom `Binding`:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject var viewModel = ViewModel()

    var binding: Binding<Bool> {
        .init(get: {
            viewModel.showRow
        }, set: { newValue in
            withAnimation {
                viewModel.showRow = newValue
            }
        })
    }

    var body: some View {
        List {
            Text("Text")
            Toggle("Toggle", isOn: binding)
                .toggleStyle(SwitchToggleStyle(tint: Color.red))
            if viewModel.showRow {
                Text("Hidden Text")
            }
        }
        .listStyle(GroupedListStyle())
    }
}
```

Comment: Actually that is even better. It's way better to have withAnimation inside the View instead the ViewModel. The idea with Binding is great.

Comment: Thanks! in my case the conditionally rendered view is inside a `Section` and the animation is not that smooth see Gif in the answer above.

Comment: not sure if this a SwiftUI animation bug, I have inspected @davidev's GIF and his animation seems smooth.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a possible solution, changing the Published value with the help of `withAnimation`

```
class ContentViewModel : ObservableObject {
    @Published var isOn : Bool = false {
        didSet {
            withAnimation {
                if isOn {
                    showRow = true
                }
                else {
                    showRow = false
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    @Published var showRow = false
}

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @ObservedObject var viewModel = ContentViewModel()
            
    var body: some View {
        
        List() {
            
            Text("Hello World")

            HStack() {
                Toggle("Test", isOn: $viewModel.isOn)
                    .toggleStyle(SwitchToggleStyle(tint: Color.red))
            }
            
            if (viewModel.showRow) {
                Text("Hello Second World")
            }
       }.listStyle(GroupedListStyle())
    }
}
```

[image]